# How do reshape an image to fit my Mnist Convolutional model?

Tags: deep-learning, scikit-learn, image-classification, image-preprocessing, mnist

***I have done research but cannot seem to find what's wrong here***

I have created this model for Mnist digit clasification :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D,Dropout,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32 , kernel_size = (3,3),activation ='relu' , input_shape = input_shape ))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation ='softmax'))
```

and I have this image to feed into the model:

[image]

So i reshaped the image like this:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.transform import resize
image = image_gray
image = resize(image, (28, 28,1)).shape
image
```

But when i try to predict using this image i get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1)
```

I have tried multiple ways using skimage but I can't seem to get the model to fit. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.predict(img)` requires a batch axis, i.e. `img` needs to have a shape of (BS, H, W, C). Try `model.predict(np.expand_dims(img,0))`.

Comment: I'm getting this error : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3)

Comment: Shouldn't this line: image = resize(image, (28, 28,1)).shape be image = resize(image, (28, 28,1)) ?

Comment: oh yeah that worked .

Comment: wait but now I'm getting this new error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1) but i think that it matches the shape right?

Comment: Did you use model.predict(np.expand_dims(img,0))? Your img array has 3 dimensions now: (H,W,C). To predict, you need a batch axis as the first dimension.

Comment: oh yes I'm so sorry I used model.predict() thanks a lot u saved my life